# What is the latest milestone release version for r3 corda? Is it 3.4 or 4.0

Tags: corda

Please help in getting the latest stable version for corda. I am not sure whether it is 3.4 or 4.0.

Answer (score 0):

It is 4.0. You can see a list of all the Corda releases here: https://ci-artifactory.corda.r3cev.com/artifactory/corda-releases/net/corda/corda/.